# From List To Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def build_placements(shoes):
    """ (list of str) -> dict of {str: list of int}
    Return a dictionary where each key is a company and each value is a
    list of placements by people wearing shoes made by that company.

    build_placements(['Saucony', 'Asics', 'Asics', 'NB', 'Saucony',
    'Nike', 'Asics', 'Adidas', 'Saucony', 'Asics'])
    {'Saucony': [1, 5, 9], 'Asics': [2, 3, 7, 10], 'NB': [4], 'Nike': [6], 
    'Adidas': [8]}

    The following is the answer:
    """
    company_to_placements = {}

    for i in range(len(shoes)):
        company = shoes[i]
        if company not in company_to_placements:
            company_to_placements[company] = []
        company_to_placements[company].append(i + 1)

    return company_to_placements
```

One thing I do not understand is why `company_to_placements[company] = []`? If a `company` is not in  `company_to_placements`, shouldn't that `company_to_placements[company] = [1]` since it is the first time for that company to appear?

Comment: You seem to be missing the closing """ for your docstring.

Comment: _"shouldn't that company_to_placements[company] = [1]?"_. If you want results like `{'Saucony': [1, 1, 5, 9], 'Asics': [1, 2, 3, 7, 10], 'NB': [1, 4], 'Nike': [1, 6], 'Adidas': [1, 8]}`, then yes.

Comment: You should look at collections.defaultdict.

Answer (score 4):

> If a company is not in  company_to_placements, shouldn't that company_to_placements[company] = [1] since it is the first time for that company to appear?

No, because you are explicitly adding the company in the next line. However, you cannot use the `list.append()` method yet if there is not yet a list in the dictionary for a given key:

```
>>> company_to_placements = {}
>>> company = 'Saucony'
>>> company_to_placements[company].append(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Saucony'
>>> company_to_placements[company] = []
>>> company_to_placements[company].append(1)
>>> company_to_placements
{'Saucony': [1]}
```

Because there is no `'Saucony'` key at first, trying to use that key to retrieve a list and call `append()` on that list object fails; a `KeyError` is thrown.

The `if company not in company_to_placements:` test simply creates the initial empty list, the next line then adds the integer to the list.

The code could be simplified to:

```
company_to_placements = {}

for i, company in enumerate(shoes, 1):
    company_to_placements.setdefault(company, []).append(i)
```

using the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to add an empty list to the dictionary if the `company` key is not yet present.

Another option would be to use [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to materialise a new list every time you try and access a key that isn't yet present:

```
from collections import defaultdict

company_to_placements = defaultdict(list)

for i, company in enumerate(shoes, 1):
    company_to_placements[company].append(i)
```